# What is a more formal synonym for "getting the job"?

Tags: synonyms, formality, writing

Example sentence:

> [X] has  become a standard threshold in the industry that [Y] has to cross to "get the job".

I would also not mind to get some other suggestions, since the overall sentence structure feels clunky, no matter how I look at it, and I am not quite sure as to why.

Comment: Do you mean job as in task? position as an employee? contract to perform works?

Comment: @Peter a job, as in get in to get paid - any professional position; no matter if contract worker or employee

Comment: Obtain employment, secure a position.

Comment: If you mean "get paid" or "get work" on contract or as a one-off (eg a photographer getting paid to photograph an event) rather than become an employee, then a lot of the suggestions won't work. Maybe "succeed professionally", "get work", "make money", "make them sign on the dotted line", or something in that area.

Comment: to get the job = to be appointed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps "to be hired" instead of "to get the job".

Comment: I guess I was looking for something greater. I accepted it for now, but I don't think I will use it, despite being correct. (I guess, sometimes we are seeing something that we cannot quite put our finger on, and I think this is one of those cases for me)